# What is possibly wrong in my gel electrophoresis when I didn't see bands of DNA ladder on gel?

Tags: gel-electrophoresis

What was possibly wrong in my gel electrophoresis when I didn't see bands of DNA ladder, and genomic DNA sample on gel ? I could see bands of genomic PCR and RNA solution.[image]

**Edit**

Thank you all of guys for sharing your opinions. From some opinions, I found out the possible error that my genomic DNA didn't show up because it was not pure (I forgot the detail that our group used a sample of DNA which was extracted from a previous lab and we didn't obtain an expected ratio for the purity of DNA. Then, we also used the impure DNA sample to do PCR, and finally used the amplified DNA for gel electrophoresis lab). However, the reason for DNA ladder didn't show up I'm not sure. I just can suppose that my groupmate who handled with DNA ladder solution possibly contaminated it.

Comment: Can you tell us how you are visualizing the gel? The answer probably revolves around the way the gel and samples are prepped and imaged.

Comment: Perhaps your ladder has gone off!

Comment: Can you show an image?

Comment: I observed it under a UV-spectrophotometer. Actually, the bands which I observed was RNA/cDNA RT-PCR product, genomic PCR product, and RNA solution, but the bands of genomic DNA sample and DNA ladder didn't show up. I set the voltage to 120 and allow to run for 30 mins which worked for my classmate.

Comment: This picture is still not very clear. Don't you have a gel-doc in your lab?

Comment: I know the image is not good. My groupmate took it.

Comment: So that isn't your ladder on the far left side of the gel?  How about some lane labels.

Comment: No, it's just a ruler on the frame of the mold. Acctually, I don't have any bands of DNA ladder and my teacher also suppose so.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not provide sufficient details required for a precise answer. Questions related to experiment troubleshooting should provide all necessary details about the experiment.

Comment: I'm not talking about the ruler.  I'm talking about what's fluorescing pink down on lane 1, starting from the left.  That looks like poorly resolved and partially degraded ladder to me.  What was your gel composition?

Comment: Just to help you with future gels, take the gel out of the plastic and put it right on the glass. The plastic can absorb some of the UV and reduce the intensity in your dye, which I'm assuming is ethidium because it's pink. Also, are you using lithium borate buffer with orange G loading buffer? The voltage and time you mention are consistent with that, and your dye front is yellow, but you have a second dark blue dye front near the top. But we shouldn't have to guess at your experimental details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly You don't mix ladder containing microtube by Sampler. You should slowly Fill and emptying Sampler for several times when pick it for use, mix it well, but do it without creating a bubble.one more thing, check your ladder by "NanoDrop"

Comment: Do you think a sample of DNA which was not pure can influence to my result? Could you explain more why creating a bubble can cause a bad result, please?

Comment: @Kim well, there are number of reason in each part of protocols lead to make bad results so each idea that friends have mentioned are also considerable and having Inappropriate sample is one of them. creating a bubble can cause a bad result because When you use small amount of Ladder so if bubble will be taken as samples, your measurements will be very low and inefficient. I propose check process of preparation of Ladder work.

Comment: @Kim can you please check your ladder by nanodrup?and compare result for each of DNA and RNA and proteins?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. You know, we just could follow a protocol which was given to us. I was doing the experiment for a class at college level. What is nanodrup?

Comment: @Kim For more information about nanodrup please visit [this](http://www.nanodrop.com/Science.aspx) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrophotometer_for_Nucleic_Acid_Measurements) links